# Why is it called a functional component?

Tags: functional-programming, functions, reactjs, component, react

A quick google search shows that the question I have has not been asked directly, and so I ask it here. For what its worth, I am learning react, and I come from a C++ background, where as far as I know, "functional components" are not a thing.

Taking from a tutorial, this seems to be a barebone example of a functional component

```
import React from 'react';
function App() 
{
        const greeting = 'Hello Function Component!';
        return <h1>{greeting}</h1>;
}
export default App;
```

It just looks like a function to me, and yet in react, it is referred to as a functional component.

- Why is the terminology, "functional component" used?
- Why not "Component Function"?
- If I simply called this a function, would react developers be confused?

Thanks.

Comment: React docs use the term "function components". However, since React itself makes use of some *functional programming* concepts, it seems that people draw a parallel with that, so it became "functional components", as there is often talk about concepts often associated with functional, such as statelessness and purity (no side effects), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the React documentation calls them [function components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components).

Up until recently, there have been two ways to create React components: using a class, or using a function. Such functions were called [stateless function components](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#stateless-function-components). A React stateless functional components was basically a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function): same inputs (i.e. props) => same outputs (i.e. rendered output).

With the introduction of hooks in React 16.8 these functions are no longer pure, because they hold some state: same inputs => different outputs.

Here is an example of a function component which is not stateless.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
    const [greeting, setGreeting] = useState('Hello Function Component!');
    const onClick = (event) => {
        setGreeting('Hello hooks!');
    }

    return <h1 onClick={onClick}>{greeting}</h1>;
}

export default App;
```

The component above renders a `<h1>Hello Function Component!</h1>` until you click it, then it will always render `<h1>Hello hooks!</h1>`.

The variable `greeting` is called [state variable](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#declaring-a-state-variable), and the React function component manages to keep track of that variable if you follow the [hooks rules](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). I think the React function components hold state by using closures, and they need the order of execution of hooks to stay the same between renders.

To sum it up, I think that calling this component just "function" is fine, as long as you keep in mind that it's not pure.